# using data-filter attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is **html** code of two pages where in one page i have written **data-filter** *attribute* which i need to apply in other html page. The way i have done it's not working.

```
<div class="grid_12" id="category-nav">
<ul id="category" class="list-of-links centered">
    <li><a href="otherpage.html" class="current-cat" data-filter="rondvaart">Rondvaart</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherpage.html" data-filter="wandelingen">Wandelingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherpage.html" data-filter="rondleidingen">Rondleidingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherpage.html" data-filter="groepsarrangementen">Groepsarrangementen</a></li>
</ul>
```

The **HTML code for** ***otherpage.html*** is

```
<article class="post" data-cat="wandelingen">
<header>
    <p class="byline">Rondvaart</p>
    <h2>Binnendieze</h2>
</header><!-- End header -->

</article><!-- End article.post -->
<article class="post" data-cat="rondleidingen">
<header>
    <p class="byline">Rondvaart</p>
    <h2>Binnendieze</h2>
</header><!-- End header -->
```

```
<article class="post" data-cat="wandelingen">
<header>
    <p class="byline">Rondvaart</p>
    <h2>Binnendieze</h2>
</header><!-- End header -->
```

**Javascript/Jquery** is:

```
var posts = $('.post');
posts.hide();

$( "#category li a" ).click(function() { 

    var customType = $( this ).data('filter'); 
    console.log(customType);
    console.log(posts.length); 

    posts
        .hide()
        .filter(function () {
            return $(this).data('cat') === customType;
        })
        .show();
});
```

Comment: It's not taking data-filter's value from page where it is given?what's the problem or any alternative for above?

Comment: You mean when you click on a link the relative data is not storing in `customType` from `var customType = $( this ).data('filter');` ?

Comment: please add the actual question to your question.

Comment: If i click on Wandelingen link,it should redirect to otherpage.html and filter but it's not happening in above code,that's actual question

Comment: @user2696142 any comment about my answer?

Comment: @Ergec i tried your solution but still not filtering data instead showing all data on click

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you are redirection on click to otherpage.html without any info about your data filter. Also it's way simpler to do this in one page not two. Check this fiddle out

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/kwPLp/

## For two page setup

**First page HTML only, no javascript**

```
<ul id="category" class="list-of-links centered">
    <li><a href="otherpage.html#rondvaart" class="current-cat" data-filter="">Rondvaart</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherpage.html#wandelingen" data-filter="">Wandelingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherpage.html#rondleidingen" data-filter="">Rondleidingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="otherpage.html#groepsarrangementen" data-filter="">Groepsarrangementen</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Second Page (otherpage.html)**

**HTML**

```
<article class="post" id="rondvaart">
    <header>
        <p class="byline">Rondvaart</p>
         <h2>rondvaart</h2>

    </header>
    <!-- End header -->
</article>
<!-- End article.post -->
<article class="post" id="wandelingen">
    <header>
        <p class="byline">wandelingen</p>
         <h2>wandelingen</h2>

    </header>
    <!-- End header -->
</article>
<!-- End article.post -->
<article class="post" id="rondleidingen">
    <header>
        <p class="byline">rondleidingen</p>
         <h2>rondleidingen</h2>

    </header>
    <!-- End header -->
</article>
<!-- End article.post -->
<article class="post" id="groepsarrangementen">
    <header>
        <p class="byline">groepsarrangementen</p>
         <h2>groepsarrangementen</h2>

    </header>
    <!-- End header -->
</article>
<!-- End article.post -->
```

**Javascript**

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.split("#");
hash = hash[1];
var posts = $('.post');
posts.hide();
$("#" + hash ).show();
```

Comment: i know it's easier to do in one page but what i want is that on one page i have done data-filter which is running fine when i click on hyperlink which is on 2nd page should filter same as it does on single page and redirect to 1st page?

Comment: my second setup gets the filter from first page and displays the proper article on second page. If this is not what you are looking for then you should tell us your main objective.